# Reference error: login is not defined (but it is defined) WHAT IS WRONG?

Tags: javascript, playframework

I am trying to call the login function on button click that will call the controller method which will handle it from there, but when I click on the button I get the error...

I tried a lot of previous answers yet none helped me in my situation. I tried moving the code to the head tag and back after the onclick call and nothing helped I still get the stupid error..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href='@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/login.css")'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a>Menu</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="@routes.HomeController.hello()">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a>Restaurants</a></li>
                    <li><a class="orange">Log in</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <p>Login</p>
    <a class="orange1" href="@routes.HomeController.signup()">Create Account</a>
    <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Email" class="prvi">
    <input id="password" type="text" placeholder="Password" class="drugi">
    <input id="submitLogin" type="button" value="Login" class="treci" onclick="login()">
 <script>
           function login () {
             var username = $('#username').value();
             var password = $('#password').value();
             var myClass = Java.type(@routes.AuthController);

             myClass.login(username, password);
         }
    </script>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

All I want is to get it working so I can move on. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem might be inside your function. You are probably having an error and that is why login can't be defined.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Anything in the Play! application log or the JavaScript log in the browser?

Comment: @David I think you are right I had a few mistakes and after I changed my code it works fine now. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Tarek-AbdurrazakChahin I will add it as an answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be inside your function. You are probably having an error and that is why login can't be defined